# Can a digital signature change for the same input data PKCS7 / SHA256

Tags: digital-signature, sha256, pkcs#7

Conceptually, can a digital signature vary if it is generated multiple times for the same input data with SHA256 hashing and PKCS7 formatting.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There are randomized signature schemes that change for every signature even with the same data.

Comment: Plus PKCS7/CMS signature can either be apllied directly to data or via 'signed attrbutes' which are often used and often contain a signing timestamp, which of course changes even a deterministic signature (@PresidentJamesK.Polk) OP: for a useful answer you need to be much more specific and probably move to security.stackexchange.com because this is not related to programming or development.

Answer (score 1):

If data is same, SHA256 hash would be same and PKCS7 signature, using same private/public key pair, may be same unless it contains time stamping.